# Keep getting login incorrect from Ubuntu on WSL

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sudo

I tried to run `sudo login` to login as the root user in Ubuntu on WSL, so it asks for my password for Ubuntu first, then windows. I use my command line in windows to find the user name should be `chanw`, then I input my password. However, I keep getting `Login incorrect` error, how can I login? Should I do this whole thing`desktop-5920u38\chanwk` as the login instead? Did I miss something?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The password will be the password for the user assigned at Linux Ubuntu level not at Windows level.

Comment: Do you mean the password for the root user for Ubuntu? But it asked that, and then asked me for the Desktop login? So do you mean to put the Ubuntu credentials when I am asked to put Desktop login? @Raman Sailopal ?

Comment: Yeah. Enter the roit password twice.

Comment: IDK why but it still doesn't work for me. Thanks anyways!